# Two login forms require seperate redirects

Tags: php, wordpress, wpmu

I have two login forms for my Wordpress Multisite site, one for logging into the web version of the app and another for logging into the mobile version of the app. The problem is that I need to redirect the different forms, after user login, to different urls.

I currently have a plugin that contains the code below that effectively redirects users who are using the web based login form:

```
function web_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request_redirect_to, $user ) 
{    
        if ($user->primary_blog) {
            $url = example.com/web_app;
            wp_redirect($url);
            die();
        }

        return $redirect_to;
}
add_filter('login_redirect','web_login_redirect', 100, 3);
```

I now need to redirect my app login to a different page, for example - example.com/app. What is the best process to do this, can this easily be built into the above function?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`wp_is_mobile();`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_is_mobile) functions.

This Conditional Tag checks if the user is visiting using a mobile device. This is a boolean function, meaning it returns either TRUE or FALSE. Works through the detection of the browser user agent string `($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])`

```
function web_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request_redirect_to, $user ) 
{    
        if ($user->primary_blog) {
            if ( wp_is_mobile() ) {
                $url = example.com/web_app;
            }else{
                $url = example.com;
            }            
            wp_redirect($url);
            die();
        }

        return $redirect_to;
}
add_filter('login_redirect','web_login_redirect', 100, 3);
```

Would you please try above code? I think It's helpful for you.

Comment: That would be great however I still need users to be able to log into the web version of the app using their mobile browser. The app login form lives in a webview within a native app, my only idea for a solution is to post an extra field with the app login form that can be used as a switch to determine the redirect url. Would this be a logical approach?

Comment: Anyone else any ideas, am really struggling here?

Comment: @user1419810 I'm not sure about that but it's possible. Would you please try once with `wp_is_mobile` function.

Comment: Sorry purvik, whilst it does work, it doesn't unfortunately solve my problem due to the fact that i still need to allow users to access the web app from their mobile browsers. I solved the issues by passing through a redirect URL then building a conditional switch of the back of an if statement.